# Removing Airflow's xcom variables isn't working with Operational Error : "Incorrect datetime value in 'execution_date' at row 1"

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am facing a strange error in airflow. I try to remove the `Xcom` variables for a task within a certain execution-date; to create and use another instance of the `Xcom`variable for the same task.

Why do I want to do this? Because the value of this `Xcom` variable changes during the day, and sometimes I notice a conflict, the first value is used, which messes up my workflows. I'd be happy to explain with examples if needed.

When I execute this query :

`SELECT * FROM xcom WHERE dag_id='datamart_integration.tracking_marketing' AND TASK_ID='find_file' AND execution_date LIKE '%2020-12-14%'`

I get 2 rows of data.

```
id  key value   timestamp   execution_date  task_id dag_id
4969    return_value    b'["DTM_DATALAKE_TRACKING_MARKETING_20201214_20201214060143.zip"]'  2020-12-14 10:22:50.085745  2020-12-14 05:40:38 find_file   datamart_integration.tracking_marketing
5139    return_value    b'["DTM_DATALAKE_TRACKING_MARKETING_20201214_20201214060143.zip", "DTM_DATALAKE_TRACKING_MARKETING_20201214_20201214130326.zip"]'   2020-12-14 16:50:55.596651  2020-12-14 13:35:44 find_file   datamart_integration.tracking_marketing
```

But when I execute this query :

`DELETE FROM xcom WHERE dag_id='datamart_integration.tracking_marketing' AND TASK_ID='find_file' AND execution_date LIKE '%2020-12-14%'`

I get

> Execution failed on sql 'DELETE FROM xcom WHERE dag_id='datamart_integration.tracking_marketing' AND TASK_ID='find_file' AND execution_date LIKE '%2020-12-14%'': (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '%2020-12-14%' for column 'execution_date' at row 1")

But I think the real problem occurs when I try these queries :

`DELETE FROM xcom WHERE dag_id='datamart_integration.tracking_marketing' AND TASK_ID='find_file' AND execution_date BETWEEN '2020-12-14 00:00:00' AND '2020-12-14 23:59:59'`

`DELETE FROM xcom WHERE dag_id='datamart_integration.tracking_marketing' AND TASK_ID='find_file' AND execution_date LIKE '2020-12-14%'`

I get

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>
> No data

I'm thinking perhaps the airflow database is protected from deletion/insertion unless specified somewhere, and somehow? But then these errors would be confusing.

The airflow_db is initiated with `MySQL`, and I'm working on composer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707132/how-to-delete-xcom-objects-once-the-dag-finishes-its-run-in-airflow didn't solve your issue?

Comment: @Elad well no, the solution `execution_date = {{ds}}` would translate to `execution_date=2020-12-14` which returns nothing for the `SELECT` statement and `'NoneType' object is not iterable` for the `DELETE` statement

Comment: Well, I tried the second solution, by going through the Xcom library programmatically, and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this exact same error, I assume you were using [Adhoc Queries](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/profiling.html#adhoc-queries) from [Data Profiling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/profiling.html#data-profiling) in Airflow's UI.

While not strictly specified in the Airflow documentation (at least not that I've found), I assume that DML statements aren't allowed to run from there; as described in the docs:

> The adhoc query UI allows for simple SQL interactions with the database connections registered in Airflow

I understand that Adhoc Queries are only meant to test connections. That's probably why SELECT statements work fine, but DELETE statements throw those errors even if the query is correct.

I can confirm that running the DELETE statements within a DAG, either from a [MySqlOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/mysql_operator.html) or through the xcom library, as you've mentioned in the comment, works fine.