# Can't access the XCom on airflow "Error code: Out of Memory"

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Well, for sure after trying my script sometimes, I forgot that the Airflow has a limit to load data and now I can't access the XComs to delete my data, is there a way to do that using the Ubuntu because I'm running my Airflow on LocalExecutor?

Here is the SS from the error

[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46707132/how-to-delete-xcom-objects-once-the-dag-finishes-its-run-in-airflow

Comment: You could also enter to the Airflow's database from an IDE and delete manually the row